# Unregistering a RedisGears registration using inline redis-cli command results in "ERR unknown command `RG_UNREGISTER`"

Tags: redis, redis-cli, redisgears

When using redis-cli, I can unregister a RedisGears registration like this:

```
127.0.0.1:16379> RG.UNREGISTER "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-4"
OK
```

When running this command as an inline redis-cli command, it fails:

```
$ redis-cli "RG_UNREGISTER 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-6"
(error) ERR unknown command `RG_UNREGISTER 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-6`, with args beginning with:
$ echo "RG_UNREGISTER 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-6" | redis-cli 
(error) ERR unknown command `RG_UNREGISTER`, with args beginning with: `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-6`,
```

How do I run RG_UNREGISTER as an inline redis-cli command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will unregister a RedisGears registration as an inline redis-cli command:

```
$ echo "RG.UNREGISTER 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-8" | redis-cli
```

This also works:

```
$ echo "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-1" redis-cli -x "RG.UNREGISTER"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also:

```
redis-cli "RG.UNREGISTER" 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-6
```

Comment: Have you tried this? It fails for me when using redis-cli 5.0.7: 
`ERR unknown command RG_UNREGISTER, with args beginning with: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000-26,`